# How to make auto-focus button when page is loaded

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I load my page, the three buttons in my `<div>` with class `"btn-group"` are not focused or activated by default. How can I make them auto-active when the page loads?

```html
<div class="btn-group" role="group">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg">Broiler</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg">Layer</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg">Free Range</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg" autofocus >Broiler</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg" >Layer</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg" >Free Range</button>
<div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).